# unable to rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sinatra

everyone one I am working on a Sinatra app. I am trying to use Active Record as my database option.  This is my first time of using Active Record with Sinatra.

I have successfully created my table, but I am getting an error whenever I try to "rake db:migrate".

I have gone through likely issues I found on Stack overflow, but not getting any headway. Any help would be appreciated.

Error message for "rake db:migrate

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Below is my Rakefile

```
require_relative './app/controllers/recipe_controller'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'
task :console do
    Pry.start
end
```

Below is my config/environment file

```
require 'bundler'
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'sqlite3',
  database: 'db/development.sqlite'
)

require './app/controllers/recipe_controller'
```

Below is config.ru file

```
require "sinatra"

require './app/controllers/recipe_controller'

run RecipeController
```

my create_recipes file

```
class CreateRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :recipes do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.boolean :completed

      t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Comment: If it says connection is not established, that means that your database is down or you are using wrong connection string

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please how do I use the right connection string? This is my first time using ActiveRecord with Sinatra

Comment: try omitting extension or different paths, check if path is relative to your application or use absolute

Comment: Is your application working or is the problem with db:migrate only?

Comment: I am just setting up the app. I need to db:migrate to continue.

Comment: It's working now. I changed my Ruby version from 3.0.3 to 2.7.0. Thank you

Comment: Provide your own question with an answer to it, then, someone could find it helpful

Comment: For the rake db_migrate to run, I changed two things. (1) I  downgraded my Ruby version from 3.0.3 to 2.7.0.  (2) I changed - gem 'sqlite3' to  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6' .

Comment: Not as a comment, please, as a real answer, and mark it as accepted